# Decode MIDI variable length field

Tags: midi, decoding, variable-length

How to decode variable length fields in MIDI? The description found at[1] does only give some examples without mentioning what happens if the most significant bit is set. This is my current code:

```
uint32_t MuStudio::MIDI::FileReader::varfieldGet()
    {
//  Note: always swap bytes on return since the loop reads in LE fashion since it
//  it cannot be known a priori how many bytes to read

    uint32_t ret=0;
    uint8_t byte_in;
    uint8_t k=0;
    while(!m_source.eof())
        {
        byte_in=m_source.byteGet();
        if(byte_in&0x80)
            {
            if(k==sizeof(ret))
                {break;}
        //  How to continue here?
            }
        else
            {return __builtin_bswap32(ret|(byte_in<<k));}
        }

    while(!m_source.eof() && byte_in&0x80)
        {byte_in=m_source.byteGet();}

    return __builtin_bswap32(ret);
    }
```

[1] http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/midiformat.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable-length values are not little endian but big endian, but this does not matter because you read them one byte at a time and construct the result in your native byte order.

When you combine a byte with the previous-read bits, you have to shift the previous bits, not the current byte.

When the most significant bit is set, you do not have to do anything special; when the bit is clear, you must stop:

```c
uint32_t varfieldGet()
{
    uint32_t ret = 0;
    uint8_t byte_in;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (m_source.eof())
            // return error
        byte_in = m_source.byteGet();
        ret = (ret << 7) | (byte_in & 0x7f);
        if (!(byte_in & 0x80))
            return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you treat overflow in ret?

Comment: This code doesn't. You could change the `for` loop.

Comment: Is the termination condition n_iter==sizeof(uint32_t)